# Prove there exists an open set $U$ with $0 \in U \subset f^{-1}(G)$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the property that for all sequences $x_n$, if $x_n \rightarrow 0$, then $f(x_n) \rightarrow 1$.
Let $G$ be an open set with $1 \in G$. Prove there exists an open set $U$ with $0 \in U \subset f^{-1}(G)$. 
[In this problem we are using the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$].

$\textbf{Proof:}$ By way of contradiction, assume $G$ is open with $1 \in G$ and $f^{-1}(G)$ is not an open set. 
Since $G$ is open and $1 \in G$, then $\exists$ open set of size $\epsilon >0$ containing $1$. We see $(-1,1) \not \subset f^{-1}(G)$ as well as $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) \not \subset f^{-1}(G)$. Thus, choose $x_1 \in (-1,1)$, $x_2 \in \left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$, ..., $x_n \in \left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$. 
By axiom of choice, $x_1$, ... $x_n \not \in f^{-1}(G)$. Hence $x_n \rightarrow 0$. 
So, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ f(x_n) \not \in G$. Thus, $f(x_n) \not \rightarrow 1$ $\Rightarrow\mspace{-2mu}\Leftarrow$ 
$\therefore$ By way of contradiction, $f^{-1}(G)$ is open and $0 \in f^{-1}(G)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: You say "By way of contradiction" but then you assume what has to be proven. This is not quite right.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you. I made an error.

Comment: I originally wrote the proof with this assumption and was told, "Setup of contradiction was incorrect. Lots of non-open sets could contain $(-1,1)$. So you should assume $f^{-1}(G)$ is open and show $0 \in f^{-1}(G)$."

Comment: Can you explain why $(-1,1) \not\subseteq f^{-1}(G)?$ I don't see any reason why this should hold.

Comment: You only need countable choice here. Not full AC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is **no** open set such that $0 \in U$ and $U \subseteq f^{-1}[G]$.

This implies that for **every** open set $U$ that contains $0$, $U \not\subseteq f^{-1}[G]$.

So we can pick for each $n$, $x_n \in (-\frac1n, \frac1n)$ such that $f(x_n) \notin G$ (i.e. $x_n \notin f^{-1}[G]$).

These $x_n \to 0$ but $f(x_n)\not\to 1$, as witnessed by $G$, which does not contain a tail of that sequence.

So this contradiction does how such a $U$ must exist.